# Django IntegrityError - can't figure it out

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

My porgram is giving an IntegrityError when there is a valid submission, that is, when (i think) the program enters the form.is_valid() branch.
Does anyone have a clue about what's causing it?

P.S: I changed the code from no form using to form using, and that's when the error started

I have the following view

```
def new_category(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = NewCategoryForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        p = Category(name=cd["name"])
        p.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("objects:index"))
    else:
        return render(request,"objects/new_category.html",{"form":form})
else:
    form = NewCategoryForm()
    return render(request,"objects/new_category.html",{"form":form})
```

and the models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("nome da categoria",max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def sorted_events(self):
        return self.event_set.order_by("start")

class Event(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    start = models.DateTimeField("horario", default=0)
```

and the form

```
class NewCategoryForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=10,
            error_messages=my_errors)

    def clean_name(self):
        if len(self.cleaned_data["name"]) < 3:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Nome demasiado curto!")
```

and the template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'objects/style.css' %}" />


<form action="{% url 'objects:new_category' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="field">
    {% for error in form.name.errors %}
        <p> {{ error }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form.name }} 
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 1:
I just ran some tests and found a somewhat weird behaviour. I sumbit a valid input, and execute

```
print request.POST
print form.is_valid()
print cd   #this one inside the if form.is_valid()
```

the output is this

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'ujlYhAFkFd7PuGJMk2aEmvWkDZmg4HlX'], u'name': [u'awdawdd']}>
True
{'name': None}
```

Why is the value of "name" being "None", if in the request.POST the "awdawdd" string is there?

EDIT 2:
More information.
Strangely enough, when i try to call form.cleaned_data right in the line before "if form.is_valid()" it says:

```
AttributeError: 'NewCategoryForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

Comment: 2 things: How is `Category` defined, and what is the stacktrace ?

Comment: I've edited, now you can see the models too

Comment: Just change `p = Category(name=cd["name"])` to `p = Category.objects.create(name=cd["name"])` and remove the `p.save()`

Comment: Why don't I need to save the object anymore? Will it be saved in the db anyways?

Comment: yes.. create saves it in the db for you

Comment: By the way, the error persists

Comment: It give a "objects_category.name may not be NULL"

Answer (score 0):

A bit of rework:

```
class NewCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name',]

    def validate_name(name):
        if len(name) < 3:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Nome demasiado curto!")
```

And in the View:

```
...
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()  # will save to DB
    return ...
else:
...
```

Or alternatively:

```
...
if form.is_valid():
    cat = form.save(commit=False)  # won't save to DB
    cat = do_stuff_with_cat
    cat.save()
    # to save another instance, one possibility is:
    cat.pk = None
    cat.save()
    return ...
else:
...
```

Comment: Isn't there a solution without such rework?
If not, could you please explain me the role of model = Category inside the Meta class? What if I wanted to save two objects from a single submit?

Comment: ModelForm is common practice when working with models. It saves you the trouble of defining fields all over again. As a matter of fact, that validator probably should have been defined on the model itself, in which case the form would just inherit it. The Meta class is a way to configure the ModelForm - tell it what model it should handle, tell it what fields it should display on the form, etc. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Comment: Before I embrace the ModelForm's, is there a way to do it like I'm doing, though? (just so that I understand what's behind this)

Comment: Can you post more detailed error message? It should be possible, definitely. You either have a required model field missing, or some typo in the name of the field ("name"), or some such. The approach is valid, so it must be a detail that's problematic.

Comment: Ah, clean_name() must return a value!